# gcp:datastore - get overall status __Stat_Total__ using Python API

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I want to get overall datastore Statistics for my Dashboard Application. I went through the docs there are no tutorials about how to get the statistics using datastore. Somehow to get the status details there is GQL Query
`SELECT * FROM __Stat_Total__` which displays
`builtin_index_bytes,
builtin_index_count, 
bytes,
composite_index_bytes, 
composite_index_count, 
count, 
entity_bytes, 
timestamp`.
I want to display all these details through Python API Client.

I tried a few examples which didn't work out.

```
def get_summary_statistics(self):
        #[START getting the Summary Statistics]
        stats = self.client.query(kind= self.kind_name)
        overall_stats = stats.__Stat_Total__ ()

        return overall_stats
```

How do I get all datastore Statistics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cloud Datastore NDB administration documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/admin#Statistics_queries) has some information about `__Stat_Total__` and other stat entities, along with a small example script that queries Datastore stats:

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import stats

global_stat = stats.GlobalStat.query().get()
print 'Total bytes stored: %d' % global_stat.bytes
print 'Total entities stored: %d' % global_stat.count
```